# Do you Model Webserver as an supporting actor in use case diagram?

Tags: uml, use-case

The boundary of the system is an mobile application. When an user tap on "upload photo", the mobile application will send the photo to the web server API. Do I link the use case "upload photo" to a supporting actor web server API?

The web server API is solely developed for an interface between the mobile application and the web-server for storing/retrieval of data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, sure. Actors are persons or systems interacting with the system under consideration. If you can identify a use case for that actor (and I'm sure you can find one) then it's a true actor.